# Slight confusion about the definition of a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

The notes for the course I am following define a homeomorphism as follows

> A function $f : X → Y$ between topological spaces is a homeomorphism if $f$ is
> a bijection, and both $f$, $f^{−1}$ are continuous. If such an $f$ exists, we say that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

My confusion here lies in what is meant by a map between two topological spaces. According to the definition of a topological space, it is an ordered pair of a set and a topology on that set. I don't see how we map between the ordered pairs.

I am aware that $X$ and $(X,\tau)$ are used interchangibly but here it seems that what the author is saying is that
$$
f:(X,\tau_X) \to (Y,\tau_Y)
$$
is a map.

Moreover, I just realised my confusion also applies to the definition of continuous.

If anybody could help I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: The map $f$  is between the sets $X$ and $Y$ and the map is continuous if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $(X, \tau_X)$ for every open set $U$ in $(Y, \tau_Y)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. So $f$ is not a map between two topological spaces but rather two sets? Moreover, by this logic, if we are told that $f:X \toY$ is continuous, how do we know which topologies we are working with? Maybe in saying it is continuous we have to specify them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition refers to topological spaces in an unhelpful way (given the definition you are working with). The initial function $f$ is posited between the underlying sets of the two topological spaces.

If $f$ is an isomorphism on the underlying sets and both $f$ and its inverse are continuous, then there is also an isomorphism between the topologies and $f$ becomes an isomorphism of topological spaces, which we call a homeomorphism.

Note that continuity is by definition with respect to the topologies which are given - without those given topologies, the notion of the possible continuity of $f$ would make no sense. So the definition does depend on the given topologies.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you.